# HTML Sudoku Table, labeled A-I down left side, letters unevenly spaced

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am doing a website for a web development class that is having us make a sudoku puzzle using tables. I got most of it right, but the instructions want the A-I down the side in each row, as a row header, like the 1-9 is a column header in the pic below. As you can see in the pic below, my A-I is not evenly spaced. I've provided a snippet of the HTML for the table, as well as the CSS for the table. I took out the subTables because I don't think they're relevant, and it saves a little space. Below that is a link to a pic of the output I'm getting, because I don't have enough reputation to post images here.

```
<tbody>
            <tr><th>A</th>
                <td  colspan="3" rowspan="3"><table class="subTable">

                    </table></td>
                <td colspan="3" rowspan="3"><table class="subTable">

                    </table></td>
                <td colspan="3" rowspan="3"><table class="subTable">

                    </table></td></tr>
            <tr><th>B</th></tr>
            <tr><th>C</th></tr>
            <tr><th>D</th>
                <td colspan="3" rowspan="3"><table class="subTable">

                </table></td>
                <td colspan="3" rowspan="3"><table class="subTable">

                </table></td>
                <td colspan="3" rowspan="3"><table class="subTable">

                </table></td></tr>                  
            <tr><th>E</th></tr>
            <tr><th>F</th></tr>
            <tr><th>G</th>
                <td colspan="3" rowspan="3"><table class="subTable">

                </table></td>
                <td colspan="3" rowspan="3"><table class="subTable">

                </table></td>
                <td colspan="3" rowspan="3"><table class="subTable">

                </table></td><tr>
            <tr><th>H</th></tr>
            <tr><th>I</th></tr>
        </tbody>
table.spuzzle, table.subTable   {border-collapse: collapse;}

table.spuzzle td {border-style: outset; border-color:gray; border-width:5px;}
table.spuzzle th {font-size:8px; color:gray;}
table.spuzzle tbody {height: 40px;}

table.subTable td {font-size:20px; color:blue; height:40px; width:40px; text-align:center;
                vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid black;}

.goldBox {background-image:url(gold.jpg); background-position:50% 50%; 
                background-repeat:no-repeat; text-align:center;}

.greenBox {background-image:url(green.jpg); background-position: 50% 50%;
                background-repeat:no-repeat; text-align:center}
```

Pic of problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by myself, and I feel like an idiot. I made two mistakes, one in the CSS, one in the HTML code for the table. In the CSS, I needed to change my
    table.spuzzle tbody {height:40px}
to
    table.spuzzle tbody th {height:40px},
and I missed a closing  tag at the end of the G table. Always make sure you have closing tags for everything. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you're using sub-tables and not putting the whole Sudoku into one table, all at the same level, see http://jsfiddle.net/R4AYW/. If you want to format certain cells differently can you not just use classes, see `.blue` in the jsfiddle I posted? I understand your formatting is more complicated and I might be missing something but a Sudoku seems like a fairly simple structure which doesn't need to be at more than one level of tables.

Comment: Like I said, it's for a web development class. I think the reason the instructions want us to use sub tables is for learning purposes. My problem is not with cell formatting, it's with spacing of table row headers, or <tr><th></th> tags being unevenly spaced in the final table. If it was up to me, I wouldn't do a Sudoku table this way, but I'm just following instructions.

Comment: Ok, someone else might have a better solution but I kind of got something working by adding a class to those vertical headers of `.vertical-header` and adding a CSS height to them of 40px. I also added a class of `.top` to A, D and G and a class of `.bottom` to C, F and I and gave them an extra height to account for the border around the inner tables.
http://jsfiddle.net/R4AYW/10/

Comment: There was also a line in your CSS, `table.spuzzle tbody {height: 40px;}`, which I don't think was doing anything so I took it out.